# Dash Plotly inside Flask App does not update/refresh data

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I have a Plotly Dashboard inside a Flask app, it works ok except the data does not refresh/update on page load.

To make this work I have to restart Flask.
Is there a better way to make it works?

My source data is a PostgreSQL DB and I load it to a pandas dataframe.